# How to set http response headers on Atmospehre socket

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I'm using Atmosphere library for the websocket communication support. I'm able to set up the Client-Server connection, to send and receive data but I have a hard time setting some security http headers on the websocket session. What i've tried so far was:
1. At the proxy level (nginx) I was trying to set the header using set_header -> no luck
2. At the application level I've tried to add the header in a post processing Filter -> again no luck
3. Tried to use PerRequestBroadcastFilter, but this messes up my stuff (I cannot establish client-server communication anymore when this filter is in place)

It looks like Atmosphere somehow cleans up all the headers I'm setting. Only the atmosphere headers are visible.

The headers I'm trying to add are:

```
res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
res.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
res.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
res.setHeader("X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies", "master-only");
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From which class the "res" variable is instantiated ?
From com.ning.http.client.Response ?

With this add setHeader once, after use addHeader method.